# Web to lead form as an attachment (PDF) to capture the data!

Tags: form, web2lead, getcontentaspdf

I am trying to capture the data with the help of a PDF file instead of a simple form (web-to-lead). is it possible?

As to provide a pdf file to the user to fill instead of a plain form and then capture and store the data in SF fields?

Here is the problem (digitalizing the inventory), I am willing to achieve:

> 1. Update the email template (Button with the link).
> 2. Attach online form link to the email template.
> 3. The customer clicks on the link and fills it by listing the items.
> 4. The customer sign (digital signature) and submit the form.
> 5. The data will be stored in Salesforce.

I am trying to use an attachment since there may be multiple lines of information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks. additional details added.